# Program to combine several PDFs so that the first page of each PDF has an odd page number

Tags: windows, pdf, document-converter

I'm looking for a program that can:

- combine several PDFs so that the first page of each PDF has an odd page number in the combined document  (e.g. by inserting a blank page if needed at the end of PDFs that have an odd number of pages)

If possible:

- easy to use (e.g. no need to write some scripts)
- work on Windows 7, but other Windows or Linux is OK too
- free

Surprisingly, [Adobe Acrobat Pro XI does not seem to allow such a PDF combination easily](https://superuser.com/q/723097/116475) (if you know how to do it with Adobe Acrobat Pro XI, please add an answer in the linked question, but ideally I'm looking for an easier/cheaper solution).

Answer (score 2):

There is [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) which is available for windows and includes a free version - the only trick you might need to use is to have a blank page to insert as needed.

There are free & paid for versions and a command line server version, (included in the free version).

If you would like to get sophisticated then install [python](http://www.python.org) and [pyPfd2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) this will allow you to set up a script that will do exactly what you need, again you will probably need a single blank page inserting where needed.  (**N.B.** Both are free).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a single page word document
2. Save as pdf
3. Combine your PDFs using pdfsam (http://www.pdfsam.org/)

**Note:** After every pdf that has odd no of pages insert the blank page pdf you had created. This is a manual process.So do it only if the pdfs to be combined are small in number